# How can I accomplish this layout in the most succinct way possible?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

[image]

Explanation: When element A is clicked the layout expands (but doesn't necessarily animate) into a more complicated one. The container (shown in green) has a width of 100%, while elements B and G (shown in blue) are of flexible width. All elements shown in red are of a fixed width.

The first state is simple enough to achieve, but I'm unsure how best to approach positioning element E between the two lines.

I've been trying things here: http://cdpn.io/LKJnm

Edit: Flexbox is an option for me, and is what I have been trying so far.

Comment: Where were these elements hiding before you did the `click`?

Comment: Probably just in `display: none;`-land. The issue isn't how to get from collapsed to expanded as much as it is how to achieve the expanded layout at all.

Comment: So you should be thinking in terms of three columns and flexbox. Frankly, though, flexbo has such shallow support right now you're making a lot of work for yourself.

Comment: I'm working on mobile-only with this and have tested flexbox on the devices I need, so that isn't an issue.